# SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error : logical error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Msg 824, Level 24, State 2, Line 1
SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error:
 incorrect checksum (expected: 0xe9f5ce21;
actual: 0xe9f5cc21).
 It occurred during a read of page (1:97249) in database
 ID 7 at offset 0x0000002f7c2000 in file
'D:\SKYTECHNEW\Database\IMSDATA001SCN.mdf'.  
Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or
system event log may provide more detail.
 This is a severe error condition that threatens
database integrity and must be corrected immediately.
Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB).
 This error can be caused by many factors;
 for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.
```

Comment: Max error severity=24!! Call some admin there! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: off-topic - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). But just search the internet for discussions about solving corruption. Your disk might be going bad as well. You have major problems that are not easily solved in a public forum.

Answer (score 0):

This message means that your database has a `corruption`.

As it says you should perform a full database consistency check (`DBCC CHECKDB`), because there can be more than one `corrupted pages`.

Update your question with the results of `DBCC CHECKDB`, your further actions depends on type of pages that are corrupted.